# (Angular 12) Button click should proceed only if a method having http call is done executing

Tags: angular, asynchronous, search

There is a search functionality where user can enter multiple search criteria in the form and on click of search button, the search operation starts.

Few of the fields are dropdown in this search criteria form. Selecting a value in dropdown triggers an API call to get certain ID which will be passed in the query in request payload to fetch search results.

The API call is made by certain method, and the search click is a separate method.
The structure looks like below -

```
/**
 * Method to capture changes in the form
 */
valueChanges(control, change) {
    if (control === TYPE1) {
        // update the search query
    } else if (control === TYPE2) {
        // get the ID by making API call
        this.getID()
    }
}

/**
 * Method to get certain ID
 */
private getId() {
    this.http.get(url, params).subscribe(res => {
        const formValue = this.reactiveForm.value
        // id fetched and saved to form value
        formValue['id'] = res.content.id
        // update the search query
    })
}

/**
 * Method to start search operation by making another API call
 */
public performSearch() {
    this.http.post(url, params).subscribe(res => {
        // get search results
    })
}
```

Problem comes when user clicks 'Search' button right after selecting the dropdown value which triggers API call. In this case, the API to get ID is still not over and search() method executes.

How to avoid this?

**P.S.** Disabling the button is my last option. I'm looking for some better options here.

Answer (score 1):

You might add a flag variable which will hold the status of `getId` method, and wait for it to finish.

You might use `BehaviorSubject`, and toggle status from `getId` method, and then subscribe to it in a new `prepareSearch` method on search button click event, and create blocking processing effect with `takeWhile`, until it's finished.

Try this, `isApiLoading$` has initial value set to `false`, to indicate it's not peforming a request, and when it does, it changes value to `true` from `getId` method, until the request is finished, and then sets it back to `false`.

When the button is clicked, `prepareSearch` method will get the latest value, and if it's false, it will perform request, otherwise it will wait until `getId` finishes:

```
private isApiLoading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

/**
 * perform search only when getId is done
 */
public prepareSearch() {
    
    this.isApiLoading$
      .pipe(
        // do not perform search until getId() is done
        takeWhile((val) => !!val)
      )
      .subscribe(
        (val) => console.log(val),
        (err) => console.log(err),
        // getId() done or not performing, now call performSearch()
        () => this.performSearch()
      );
  }

    
/**
 * Method to get certain ID
 */
private getId() {

    // block peform search
    this.isApiLoading$.next(true);

    this.http.get(url, params).subscribe(res => {
        const formValue = this.reactiveForm.value
        // id fetched and saved to form value
        formValue['id'] = res.content.id
        // update the search query

        // unblock perform search 
        this.isApiLoading$.next(false);

    })
}
```